# Want to use JConsole in Performance Testing

Tags: java, oracle, jconsole

Just want to know that is JConsole is good to use for perfoamance testing. Is JConsole create any issue under load test??

Comment: I would advise that you don't attach jconsole, visualvm or any other profiler during a load test for which you want to gather execution stats. I would instead run your load test with jconsole (visualvm, yourkit) attached to identify issues to be fixed/ improved between stats-gathering runs (but turn off for the runs themselves).

Answer (score 1):

`JConsole` is good tool, but i prefer to use `visualVM`, its free and more powerful tool to track the J2EE performance application, some of its features:

- Provide a CPU profiling.
- Provide all info about Threads.
- Provide the JVM Heap and the memory states.
- Provide Info about the GC activities.

And its not creating any issue, it maybe has some performance impact in the load test, but you will not notice that.